# typing variable when using subclasses in TypeScript (RxJS)

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I have a problem while writing tests for Angular using RxJS.

I have a variable which is used as a mocking provider (actions$) which is typed as "Observable". Now I assign an instance of a subclass to it (ReplaySubject). But now the method "next" is unknown (at least in Typescript) because it's not provided by "Observable" as it is from one of the subclasses "Subject".

How can I type my variable "actions$" correctly or how can I cast correctly to fix the error message?

online example: https://ngrx.io/guide/effects/testing
see line 12 vs 41

RxJS implementation

```
export declare class ReplaySubject<T> extends Subject<T> {
   ...
}

export declare class Subject<T> extends Observable<T> implements SubscriptionLike {
    ...
    next(value?: T): void;
    ...
}
```

my code

```
let actions$: Observable<any>;

actions$ = new ReplaySubject(1);

// Property 'next' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'.
actions$.next(new someThing());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should type `actions$` as `Subject<any>` or—if you want even more specificity—`ReplySubject<any>`. `Subject` extends `Observable`, so it will work for `hot` and `cold` functions if you're using `jasmine-marbles`.

As for the documentation you referenced, I suspect the `actions` being typed as `Observable` is a mistake in print.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes the example from NgRx is not correct. On line 34 the variable gets another type which is "TestHotObservable" and which is not a subclass of "Subject" or "ReplaySubject". So I think it's not possible to type the variable correctly with this example.